# How do I change the password value when onfocus is selected for username?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" onfocus="if (this.value=='Email') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Email'" value="Email" /> 
</div>
<div class="col">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="password" onkeypress="onEnterLogin(event);" /> 
</div>
```

How can I change the value of password when the username textfield is selected?

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('password')` instead of `this`? (Not that `on*` attributes are the greatest thing in the first place.) … also, why would you want to do this?

Comment: When the user clicks the username textfield, I want to empty the password textfield as well.

Comment: @minitech - Could you please share a link (or throw some light) on why on* attributes are not good? Is it related to code readability or any other reasons? I am interested in knowing. Sorry for posting this as comment. But I thought it would be apt to ask here.

Comment: @Prash: Yes, it’s pretty much code readability :) It makes things easier to maintain, when you only have to change one instance of something, and it looks cleaner and more separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@minitech: Thank you! This is what I did and it works perfectly.

```
<div class="col">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" onfocus="if (this.value=='Email') this.value = ''; document.getElementById('password').value = '';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Email'; document.getElementById('password').value = 'password';" value="Email" /> 
</div>
<div class="col">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="password" onkeypress="onEnterLogin(event);" /> 
</div>
```